# Post request string to localhost in scala akka

Tags: scala, http, akka

I have implemented an actor for doing health checks for akka actor.
This actor checks the health and returns up, down or unknown as a status.

```scala
val actorSystemCheckRunnable = 
  new ActorSystemCheckRunnable(
    actorSystemHealthChecker,
    healthCheckHost,
    healthCheckPort
  )
```

The class is declared as below

```scala
case class ActorSystemCheckRunnable(
    kinesisActorSystemHealthChecker: ActorSystemHealthChecker,
    healthCheckHost: String,
    healthCheckPort: Int
) extends Runnable {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    kinesisActorSystemHealthChecker.checkActorSystem() match {
      case t@_ => logger.info(s"${system.name} is ${t.toString}")
    }
  }
}
```

And it is scheduled as below

```scala
appHealthActorSystem
  .scheduler
  .scheduleWithFixedDelay(0 seconds, 5 seconds)(actorSystemCheckRunnable)(appHealthEC)
```

Once running it returns the output as a log

```
[app-health-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] - source is UP {}
[app-health-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] - source is UNKNOWN {}
```

But I have trouble exposing these health check outputs to the localhost.
Is there a way I can do the declaration for HTTP post from within the case class?

Edit :

I am running it as a standalone app and I did try creating an http endpoint and routing the actor system health check to that but the endpoint only remain static and shows the first health check status and in case of app going down i,e unknown or down status , it does not reflect on the endpoint

```
case class ActorSystemCheckRunnable(kinesisActorSystemHealthChecker: ActorSystemHealthChecker, healthCheckHost: String, healthCheckPort: Int) extends Runnable {
override def run(): Unit = {
  kinesisActorSystemHealthChecker.checkActorSystem() match {
    case t@_ => Http().newServerAt("localhost", 9000).bindFlow(path("hello") {
      Directives.put {
        complete(s"${system.name} is ${t.toString}")
      }
    })
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to define a http route which will perform this health check on hit ?

Comment: Updated the original post

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the app in an akka cluster, then it's no harm to bring in akka-management dependency and do health check in akka-management's way, for example:

```scala
class KinesisHealthCheck(system: ActorSystem) extends (() => Future[Boolean]) {
  private val kinesisActorSystemHealthChecker = ...
  override def apply(): Future[Boolean] = {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then configure the health check route. Please refer to https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-management/current/healthchecks.html

Or, if you don't want to include akka-management dependency for any reason, then you can create an HTTP endpoint /healthcheck using Akka HTTP, and call the endpoint just as calling any normal HTTP endpoint